# Checking bitmask: x & b != 0 VS x & b == b

Tags: binary, bitmask

Suppose `x` is a bitmask value, and `b` is one flag, e.g.

```
x = 0b10101101
b = 0b00000100
```

There seems to be two ways to check whether the bit indicated by `b` is turned on in `x`:

```
if (x & b != 0)    // (1)
if (x & b == b)    // (2)
```

In most circumstances it seems these two checks always yield the same result, given that `b` is always a binary with only one bit turned on.

However I wonder is there any exception that makes one method better than another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if we interpret both values as bit **sets**, the first condition checks if the intersection of x and b is not empty (or, to put it differently: if b and x have elements in common), while the second one checks if b is a subset of x.

Clearly, if b is a singleton, b is a subset of x if and only if the intersection is not empty.

So, whenever you cannot guarantee to 100% that b is a singleton, choose your condition wisely. Ask yourself if you want to express that all elements of b must also be elements of x, or that there are elements of b that are also elements of x. It's a huge difference **except** for the single bit case.

Comment: Thanks, `x & b == b` <==> "b is subset of x" is very useful.